# How to convert each image format to PNG in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, blob, png

When user upload a photo, they can select jpg and png. But I would store each file as PNG in S3. Is it any easy way to convert the File / Blob to Png?

Comment: What does this have to do with react? What have you tried so far? Please share a [mcve]

Comment: Start with a google search this is not a complicated matter.

Comment: @DeyanPetrov I did not find, would you show an example?

Comment: You can as well restrict the file field to .png only.

Comment: yes, I could restrict ..